# How to display JSON data using jquery DOM selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to display `json.articles[i].title` of each news on my website here is my screenshot of website and my code:

In main.js:

```
(function() {

    $.getJSON('https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=techcrunch&sortBy=top&apiKey=my-api-key', function(json) {
        $("#sidebar-wrapper li").each(function() {
            $('li').html(json.articles[0].titles)
        });
    });
})();
```

My HTML file :

```
<div id="sidebar-wrapper">
    <ul class="sidebar-nav">
        <strong>Latest Headines</strong>
        <li>
            <a href="">Your news title</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Your news title</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Your news title</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Your news title</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="">Your news title</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is my screenshot of website I want to display each news title from `json.articles[].title` instead of "Your news title".(For clarification see screenshot and HTML code).

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Below Code

```js
    (function () {

        $.getJSON('https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=techcrunch&sortBy=top&apiKey=045089075bc74354be01b34f6335d32b', function (json) {
            var html = "";
            $(json.articles).each(function (index, value) {
                $(".sidebar-nav").append("<li><a href='"+value.url+"'>" + value.title + "</a></li>");
            });
            

        });
    })();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sidebar-wrapper">
                    <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                    </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: if `LI` and `<a>` is created dynamically it will become difficult to style them later. Will it be ?

Comment: You can add class on `li` and and `<a>` that will work

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to iterate through the articles you can use an iterator index and keep incrementing it. Something like this.

```
(function(){
    var i = 0;
    $.getJSON('https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=techcrunch&sortBy=top&apiKey=045089075bc74354be01b34f6335d32b',function(json) {
            $("#sidebar-wrapper li").each(function(){
            $('li').html(json.articles[i++].titles)
        });
        });
})();
```

But you it would be better to iterate over the articles object and create lists dynamically.

Comment: @rockstone, Why are you begging for upvote, are you here for votes?

Comment: @Diwas Joshi you have declared `var i = 0` but what if I want to add images, description, titles of NEWS should I make a separate variable for each iteration. What is good practice followed by developers.

Comment: @rockstone depends on where these images, description are. if these are in article iterator works. you won't need separate iterators for these. but as in the answer adding lists dynamically would be better.

Answer (score 1):

You should dynamically create the `LI` elements, as the no of article from JSON response may vary.

To create element use [`jQuery(html)`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery2)

```
//Cache the ul element
var ul = $("#sidebar-wrapper ul.sidebar-nav");
//iterate the articles
$.each(json.articles, function(index, article) {
  //Create anchor
  var anchor = $('<a>', {
    href: article.url,
    text: article.title
  });
  //Create LI and append anchor after append the LI to UL
  $('<li>').append(anchor).appendTo(ul);
});
```

```js
(function() {

  $.getJSON('https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=techcrunch&sortBy=top&apiKey=045089075bc74354be01b34f6335d32b', function(json) {
    var ul = $("#sidebar-wrapper ul.sidebar-nav");
    $.each(json.articles, function(index, article) {
      var anchor = $('<a>', {
        href: article.url,
        text: article.title
      });
      $('<li>').append(anchor).appendTo(ul);
    });
  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sidebar-wrapper">
  <strong>Latest Headines</strong>
  <ul class="sidebar-nav">
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: but if I dynamically create `LI` elements will it affect on loading data on website also instead if I want to display images should I dynamically create <img>. So my question is should I make HTML tags and then populate it using jquery or should I dynamically create it using jquery.

Comment: need your help here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44591722/why-i-am-getting-503-error-site-overloaded-capacity

Answer (score 1):

You can also update li data by using class

**Try This**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <script> $(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON('https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=techcrunch&sortBy=top&apiKey=045089075bc74354be01b34f6335d32b',function(json) {
        var x=document.getElementsByClassName("title");
        for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++)
            x[i].innerHTML = json.articles[0].titles;
    }); }); </script>

<div id="sidebar-wrapper">
                    <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                            <strong>Latest Headines</strong>
                        <li>
                            <a href="" class="title">Your news title</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="" class="title">Your news title</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="" class="title">Your news title</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="" class="title">Your news title</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="" class="title">Your news title</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>  </div>
```

Comment: but I want to display different NEWS in each `li` element.

Comment: if you notice this line "x[i].innerHTML = json.articles[0].titles;" by using x[i] you can differentiate different li tags