# Why I am getting 503 error site overloaded capacity?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am setting attribute using attr("href","URL to original NEWS") in jquery(see the code). When I click on the NEWS title it opens the original article on NEWS website. Why am I getting 503 error site overloaded capacity(see screenshot) as I am not sending an request other than for getting JSON data. I am also getting time out error. How can I fix such error's ?

code:

```
<div id="sidebar-wrapper">
                <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                        <strong>Latest Headines</strong>
                    <li>
                        <a href="" class="title">Your news title</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="" class="title">Your news title</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="" class="title">Your news title</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="" class="title">Your news title</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="" class="title">Your news title</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

In javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$.getJSON('https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=techcrunch&sortBy=top&apiKey=my-api-key',function(json) {
        console.log(json);
        console.log(json.articles.length);

        for(var i = 0 ; i<json.articles.length ; i++){
            $(".title").eq(i).html(json.articles[i].title); 
            $(".title").eq(i).attr("href",json.articles[i].url);
        }

    });
});
```

My screenshot of console:

[image]

Comment: I believe that's pretty explicit, the site (server) is overloaded and over capacity, and can't reply for the moment. Looks like it's a tiny server.

Comment: @JeremyThille Did you got my question? I have displayed NEWS articles title using JSON data see -> http://imgur.com/a/lzLFj but when I click on them it gives me error 503 how can I overcome this issue?

Comment: @rockstone he got your question entirely. The problem is that the site cannot respond right now, and is reporting that it's overloaded. You need to fix that, assuming it's your server. Maybe it's out of memory or disk, or is under a (D)DOS attack, we can't say. If it's not your server, you need to notify the site owner.

Comment: @ADyson  Ok thanks I will look into it.